# servicemix, oracle datasource, connection pooling, max connections

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm trying to configure connection pooling in servcemix 4.4.1. I've created a oracle datasource object and set the properties like user, password,url. I deployed the following xml as osgi service in my smx.

Here's my datasource configuration:

```
    <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"> 

     <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"> 
     <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@connection:url"/> 
 <property name="user" value="****"/> 
 <property name="password" value="*****"/>


 </bean> 

 <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"> 
 <service-properties> 
 <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="oracleds"/> 
 </service-properties> 
 </service> 
 </blueprint>
```

The datasource object is created succesfully and I'm able to retrieve the object using jndi lookup in my bundle.

Now I want to apply connection pooling for which I need to declare "maximum connections". Please suggest me how can I declare max no. of connections in the above xml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of my blueprint.xml:

```
<blueprint     xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation=
            "http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd"
    default-activation="eager">

    <cm:property-placeholder id="server.placeholder" persistent-id="test.datasource">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
            <cm:property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
            <cm:property name="defaultReadOnly" value="false" />
            <cm:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
            <cm:property name="maxActive" value="100" />
            <cm:property name="whenExhaustedAction" value="2" />
            <cm:property name="maxWait" value="-1" />
            <cm:property name="maxIdle" value="8" />
            <cm:property name="minIdle" value="1" />
            <cm:property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
            <cm:property name="testOnReturn" value="true" />
            <cm:property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="-1" />
            <cm:property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3" />
            <cm:property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
            <cm:property name="testWhileIdle" value="false" />
            <cm:property name="softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="-1" />
            <cm:property name="lifo" value="true" />
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value= "${driverClassName}" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.host}:${db.port}:${db.instance}" />
      <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
      <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
      <property name="maxIdle" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
      <argument ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool" >
      <argument><null/></argument>
      <argument value="${maxActive}" />
      <argument value="${whenExhaustedAction}" />
      <argument value="${maxWait}" />
      <argument value="${maxIdle}" />
      <argument value="${minIdle}" />
      <argument value="${testOnBorrow}" />
      <argument value="${testOnReturn}" />
      <argument value="${timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />
      <argument value="${numTestsPerEvictionRun}" />
      <argument value="${minEvictableIdleTimeMillis}" />
      <argument value="${testWhileIdle}" />
      <argument value="${softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis}" />
      <argument value="${lifo}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory" >
      <argument ref="connectionFactory" />
      <argument ref="connectionPool" />
      <argument><null/></argument>
      <argument value="${validationQuery}" />
      <argument value="${defaultReadOnly}" />
      <argument value="${defaultAutoCommit}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="poolingDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource" depends-on="pooledConnectionFactory">
      <argument ref="connectionPool" />
    </bean>

    <service interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="poolingDataSource"> <!--ref="oracleDataSource"-->
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/testdb"/>
            <entry key="datasource.name" value="jdbc/testdb" />
        </service-properties>
    </service>

</blueprint>
```

This datasource work fine.
I think the attribute "maxActive" close to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between two ways:

- use oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource as datasource class
- use commons-dbcp https://gist.github.com/splatch/2d631ec09f9be0730b1e (this is fork of somebody else gist)